# How to draw an elliptical PAD in Eagle

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I am trying to design a PCB layout for a component which requires elliptical pads. I am trying to do it with two arcs but I didn't get an ellipse.
Can anyone suggest how to draw ellipse on eagle? Is there a best way?

[image: PCB layout]

Comment: The software I use (gEDA) only does circles, rectangles or rounded lines.  I use two circles overlapping, with a rectangle to bridge the gap, or a very short, very fat, line. Can't help with Eagle though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, Eagle does not have an option to place an elliptical pad. However, there is a "Roundness" property that can be used to very closely approximate an ellipse. Place a rectangular pad, click the info button [image], and select the pad.

[image]

The Roundness property has the effect of rounding the corners. You can choose a percentage between 0% and 100%. Near 100% makes a rectangle similar to an ellipse.

Here's the progression of roundness for a pad using similar dimensions as your drawing above:

[image]